# Using `instance_eval`

Tags: ruby

I am reading why's poignant guide to ruby, and in chapter 6, he used this code:

```
class Creature
  # Get a metaclass for this class
  def self.metaclass; class << self; self; end; end

  ...

  def self.traits( *arr )
    # 2. Add a new class method to for each trait.
    arr.each do |a|
      metaclass.instance_eval do
        define_method( a ) do |val|
          @traits ||= {}
          @traits[a] = val
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Why is he calling `instance_eval` on metaclass of class `Creature`? Since `instance_eval` adds methods to `metaclass`, he can just do this:

```
def self.metaclass; self; end;
```

Or am I wrong? Are there any more elegant solutions to this?

Comment: As much as I love the poignant guide, it's hopelessly outdated when it comes to metaprogramming. All _why is trying to do is call `define_method` on the `metaclass` object, which is now trivial with `define_singleton_method`.

Answer (score 3):

The simpler way to write _why's code would be just

```
def self.traits( *arr )
  # 2. Add a new class method to for each trait.
  arr.each do |a|
    metaclass.define_method(a) do |val|
      @traits ||= {}
      @traits[a] = val
    end
  end
end
```

The only problem here is that you get an error:

```
private method `define_method' called for metaclass (NoMethodError)
```

A private method can only be called with an implicit receiver i.e. the problem is the explicit `metaclass.` before the method call. But if we remove that, the implicit receiver (`self`) is `Creature`! So how do we change `self` to a different object? `instance_eval`:

```
metaclass.instance_eval do
  define_method(a) do |val|
    ...
  end
end
```

So it's really just a way of bypassing the fact that `define_method` is private. Another way to hack it would be to use `send`

```
metaclass.send(:define_method, a) do |val|
  ...
end
```

But these days all of that is totally unnecessary; you are allowed to define methods in the metaclass (AKA singleton class) without hacking around private methods:

```
def self.traits( *arr )
  # 2. Add a new class method to for each trait.
  arr.each do |a|
    define_singleton_method(a) do |val|
      @traits ||= {}
      @traits[a] = val
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
def self.metaclass; self; end;
```

you  will have a reference to `Creature` class. So, in that case, the methods will be defined not to the singleton class of object `Creature` but to the class `Creature` itself(to the list of instance methods of class `Creature`). The method

```
def self.metaclass; class << self; self; end; end
```

is a simple way to retrieve singleton class of object `Creature` in ruby < 1.9. In ruby 1.9+ was implemented method `singleton_class` which is shortcut of `class << self`. So that code can be simplified as:

```
class Creature

  ...

  def self.traits( *arr )
    # 2. Add a new class method to for each trait.
    arr.each do |a|
      singleton_class.instance_eval do
        define_method( a ) do |val|
          @traits ||= {}
          @traits[a] = val
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: But instance_eval defines methods on singleton class of object? Why do I need to pass singleton class to instance_eval?

Comment: `instance_eval` or `class_eval` or `module_eval` are very similar. They are just executes a block (in case if you pass a block) within the object they are called. So when you call `Creature.instance_eval { define_method(:m) { ... } }` it is equal to `class Creature; def :m; ...; end;`. Because you have `Creature` class in block's of eval context. You can simple check this by doing `Creature.instance_eval { p self }`. And in the case of your example, a "class method" is defined but not the instance method of `Creature` class.

Comment: BTW: we now not only have `Object#singleton_class`, but also `Object#define_singleton_method`, which makes all this song and dance unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah, right. It was just to explain about `instance_eval` and metaclass